# Best way to get underlying data from MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory-management

The bytes are written to MemoryStream object and there is a need to get underlying buffer to save it to file

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
// ms.Write(...)
// ms.Write(...)
// etc... some bytes are written to the stream

byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
int length = data.Length;
```

However the returned `data` is of `ms` capacity rather than the real `ms` length.

Is it better (faster, safer, ...) to set `ms` capacity to its length or allocate a `data` and copy `ms` contents into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the member-method `ms.ToArray()`

Answer (score 3):

GetBuffer() was designed to avoid the potentially expensive array allocation.  You can use the ToArray() method is you want a byte[] that's of the right size.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't seek around to random places, you can also use the stream position:

```
Debug.Log("All length: " + (int)ms.Position);
```